# Countable product of finite spaces has no isolated point

Tags: metric-spaces

Let each $X_i$ be a finite metric space. Define $X = \prod_{i\geq 1} X_i$ to be the product space equipped with the uniform metric, ie.

$$\rho_{\infty}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \sup_{i\geq 1} d(x_i,y_i)$$

Show that $X$ contains no isolated points.

---

This question was given to me in an analysis course, but I have a feeling that it is false. Consider each $X_i = \{0,1\}$ with $d(0,1)=d(1,0)=1$. This is a metric space, of course, with $d(0,0)=d(1,1)=0$, $d(1,0) = d(0,1) = 1$, and $d(0,1) \leq d(0,0) + d(1,0)$ and vice versa.

If that is the case, however, then take $x = (0,0,\dots)$ and consider the ball $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \{x\}$. Clearly this is a contradiction.

Am I correct? Is the question presented in its current form false?

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: Yes, the question in the OP form is false. Perhaps you copied it incorrectly? Missed some conditions?

Comment: Note that $\rho_\infty$ even need not be well-defined at all. But if it is, e.g. when we take all metrics as $0$-$1$ discrete, the resulting product is discrete, showing a counterexample.